# DevExpress CheckButton not toggeling?

Tags: vb.net, button, devexpress, toggle

I have some farmiliaraty with VB.net, but as of yeaterday only 1 day experiance with DevExpress. The functions seam quite easy but the occasional question is bound to pop-up.

My first question is:

How can I create a toggel button which toggels the timer on or off using the DevExpress "Check button" control. the code I have currently in use will only stop my timmer but not restart it when I click my Checkbutton control a second time?

```
     Private Sub CheckButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckButton1.CheckedChanged
        If True Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        Else
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [CheckButton.Checked](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsCheckButton_Checkedtopic) property as follows:

```
Private Sub CheckButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckButton1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckButton1.Checked Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    Else
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```